# Google Translate API - English subscripts to translated script

Tags: google-api, google-translate

I am trying to convert English to Hindi via Google's API but I also need the English translation of the Hindi string.

To illustrate, if I convert

> "a quick brown fox...."

to Hindi , it reads

> "फुर्तीली भूरी लोमड़ी आलसी कुत्ते के उपर से कूद गई।"

But if you look at the web interface, Google also translates the Hindi version as

> "phurtilee bhoori lomdi ..".

This doesn't show up in the response format of Translate API. I tried searching all their docs but this is all I got https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate#translatetextresponsetranslation and it just has a translated text in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Translation API does not currently offer phonetic translation, despite being available in the web interface.

You can file a request for that feature to be included in the API by following the procedure explained in [this forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/j7gLkXqdwkw;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/category$3Ahow-do-i%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) where your same question is made.

Comment: HI @VikramMurthy: were you able to get this resolved ? Thanks.

Comment: @user4848830 nope .. the API still doesn't support it .. i missed filing a request since we decided to do this in house ..its still a WIP though